# How can multiple vim users of a single user profile use different .vimrc files and settings?

Tags: bash, vim

I and several colleagues work currently using a single linux user profile. This brings about the problem with everybody wanting to have different .vimrc settings.

I actually want to create a custom .vimrc_custom file, if possible, and whenever I start vim from my bash - load the settings from this it.

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-u` option:

> -u {vimrc}
>   Use the commands in the file {vimrc} for initializations. All the other initializations are skipped. Use this to edit a special kind of files. It can also be used to skip all initializations by giving the name "NONE". See ":help initialization" within vim for more details.

So you should be able to use:

```
vim -u .vimrc_custom
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work by me. It just opens a new file in vim, but nothing more. It isn't permanent as well.

Comment: Of course it's not permanent. If it were saved in your profile, it would affect all the users who use the same profile.

Comment: When I actually run :source .vimrc_custom from within vim - it works. Can I somehow make an alias in the, let's say, .bashrc file? Something like:
alias myvim='vim source .vimrc_custom'?

Comment: I got the above option from https://linux.die.net/man/1/vi, I don't know why it doesn't work for you. There's also a `-c` option to execute a command after starting up. You should be able to put either of these options in your alias.

Answer (score 2):

You can start Vim with a custom `vimrc` with:

```
$ vim -Nu ~/.vimrc_custom
```

If that's too much to type, you can add an alias to "your" init file:

```
alias myvim='vim -Nu ~/.vimrc_custom'
```

See `$ vim --help`.

Comment: Why the `-N` option?

Comment: I suggested `-u` in my answer, his comments say it doesn't work for him.

Comment: Then he doesn't know what he is doing or he doesn't use Vim. Or both. `-N` forces "nocompatible mode".

Comment: It actually only worked like that:
alias myvim='vim . -Nu .vimrc_custom'